# Someone being mean to someone else

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know the meaning of "My dad's being mean to me."

Comment: Mean, spiteful, not nice, rude.

Comment: This is a common phrase that any 5-year-old would say. The question probably belongs on ELL.

Answer (score 2):

This means your Dad is doing or saying (or not doing/saying) things that make you unhappy. It may even mean he does these things because he wants you to be less happy. Being mean, in this context, is the opposite of being kind and friendly.